# Understanding string.gsub in Lua

Tags: string, lua, gsub

I'm trying to print a `gsub` string (in Lua) to `stdout` here how my code look like.

```
print('string.gsub(\'VEECTORY\',\'EE\',\'I\') =>', string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I'))
```

Everytime I run this, although I get the desired result but I see `1` appearing in the output.

So, the output look like this.

```
string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I') =>     VICTORY 1
```

I'm unable to understand what does that `1` stand for but if I used a variable I don't see that `1` anymore.

```
local replace_string = string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I')

print('string.gsub(\'VEECTORY\',\'EE\',\'I\') =>',replace_string)
```

I get output as

```
string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I') =>     VICTORY
```

I also notice that when I run the above code in Lua console
i.e this code

```
 local replace_string = string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I')

 print('string.gsub(\'VEECTORY\',\'EE\',\'I\') =>',replace_string)
```

I get the output as `nil`

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you kidding? Have you read anything about language and its libraries?
http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html - Lua guide; http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial - Lua string tutorail. Gosh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) has two return values. The first is result string, while the second is the total number of matches that occurred.

In your example:

```
string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I')
```

The second return value is `1` because the substitution happened once.

When you assign the result as:

```
local replace_string = string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I')
```

The first return value is assigned to `replace_string`, while the second return value is discarded.

You can get the second return value explicitly by:

```
local replace_string, num = string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I')
```

---

Finally, in interactive mode, each line is a chunk by itself, so the local variables are out of scope in the next line, therefore you saw `replace_string` becomes `nil`. If you use global variables:

```
replace_string = string.gsub('VEECTORY','EE','I')
print('string.gsub(\'VEECTORY\',\'EE\',\'I\') =>',replace_string)
```

The output will be as expected in interactive mode as well.

Comment: Can explain what you mean by `each line is a chunk, so the local variables are out of scope in the next line`

Comment: @Ratatouille [PiL 4.2 – Local Variables and Blocks](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html).